# hit curl request when the server starts

Tags: php

I am trying to send curl request from my php server to another php server when the server starts.

So far i have not been able to identify any server startup event in php. I can send curl when there is some user event, but not automatically at server startup.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PHP usually runs under Apache for handling web requests. If you want to do something outside of that context, use the [PHP CLI](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). You can add then add this PHP script to your standard [Linux init scripts](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html). But if all you want to do is make a [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request, why not just use the [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) command-line utility?